# Unable to Spellcheck Correctly using LanguageTool Java API

Tags: java, nlp, spell-checking, languagetool

I am trying to correct some misspelled words present in a text file using LanguageTool Java API. After going through LT wiki and https://languagetool.org/ I tried some example codes -

```
JLanguageTool langTool;
String text = "I.- Any reference _in this Section to a panicular genus or species of an anirmgl, cxccpl where the context";
langTool = new JLanguageTool(Language.AMERICAN_ENGLISH);
langTool.activateDefaultPatternRules();

List<RuleMatch> matches = langTool.check(text);
for (RuleMatch match : matches) {
          System.out.println("Potential error at line " +
                match.getEndLine() + ", column " +
                match.getColumn() + ": " + match.getMessage());
          System.out.println("Suggested correction: " +
                match.getSuggestedReplacements());
}
```

The output is as follows -

```
Potential error at line 0, column 19: Possible spelling mistake found
Suggested correction: [Lin, Min, ain, bin, din, fin, gin, in, kin, min, pin, sin, tin, win, yin]
Potential error at line 0, column 41: Possible spelling mistake found
Suggested correction: []
Potential error at line 0, column 74: Possible spelling mistake found
Suggested correction: []
Potential error at line 0, column 83: Possible spelling mistake found
Suggested correction: []
```

Expected Ouput -

```
Starting check in English (American)...
1. Line 1, column 19
Message: Possible spelling mistake found (deactivate)
Correction: in; win; bin; pin; tin; min; Lin; din; gin; kin; yin; ain; fin; sin; IN; In; Min; PIN
Context: I.- Any reference _in this Section to a panicular genus or sp...
2. Line 1, column 41
Message: Possible spelling mistake found (deactivate)
Correction: particular; funicular
Context: ...I.- Any reference _in this Section to a panicular genus or species of an anirmgl, cxccpl ...
3. Line 1, column 74
Message: Possible spelling mistake found (deactivate)
Correction: animal
Context: ...n to a panicular genus or species of an anirmgl, cxccpl where the context
4. Line 1, column 83
Message: Possible spelling mistake found (deactivate)
Context: ...nicular genus or species of an anirmgl, cxccpl where the context
Potential problems found: 4 (time: 171ms)
How you can improve LanguageTool
```

I got this output from LT standalone Desktop software. I compared its installation folders and its contents with my source code and API jars but could not find anything special which is making the former a better solution.

Also, I want to replace the misspelled words with the first element in suggestion list.

**Any kind of help will be highly appreciated.**

Comment: we would like to know how you configured languagetool in your project and what IDE were you using ? here is a link to our question If you have time to take a look https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58310085/javafx-class-not-found-exception-at-run-time and comment it would be greatly appreciated thanks

Answer (score 1):

I was using old Languagetool jar. Please use this -

```
<dependency>
<groupId>org.languagetool</groupId>
<artifactId>language-en</artifactId>
<version>3.5</version>
</dependency>
```

Also, the spell correction can be done by selecting misspelled words from (match.getFromPos() to match.getToPos()) and replacing it with the most convincing word from suggestion list (its upto the programmer to choose the word).

Hope it may be helpful.

Comment: `3.5` is what's up-to-date now, it will also be outdated in 3 months. So please use the version given at http://wiki.languagetool.org/java-api, we keep that page updated. (Disclosure: I'm the maintainer of LanguageTool)